# How to add a variable constrain to a view

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I am having a chat view where each chat bubble is being shown with messages either left or right. I am using constraint layout for the same , its like whatsapp chat bubbles with the time appearing at the end of the text , I am able to do that but the layout causes the bubble to exceed the recyclerview and beyond that.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cellLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_msg_right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Lets   &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewSender"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="10:00pm"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewMain"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewTime"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Sender"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewMain"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewMain"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here cellLayout exceeds the width , I want to know how to add left constraints to it so that it would keep maximum margin of 30dp and not exceed the view.

[image]

Can anybody suggest ? how to stop the cellLayout exceed the width ? ALl I want is not to add fixed constant width or constraint to it else for smaller text it will still show bigger bubles.

[image]

Comment: Give android:layout_marginStart="4dp" to ImageView

Comment: @ArnoldBrown how does that solves the issue ?

Comment: the xml above corresponds to a message aligned left (from having an `end` margin). what are you using for messages aligned right?

Answer (score 0):

Above expected behaviour can be obtained by setting maxWidth, I set maxWidth for texViewMain while creating holder object in the adapter of recyclerview.